# Click and select a vertical slice of an image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to achieve the following thing:
When the user to click an image, a selection 'div' is created at the mouse.x coordinate and the user can resize this div horizontally. On 'mouseup', the page is redirected to another page. Here is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function myDrag(evt,e)
    {
    var id="sel"+e.id;
    var startX= evt.pageX;
    var mouseX = evt.pageX - e.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = evt.pageY - e.offsetTop ; 
    var child=document.getElementById(id);
    if(child==null)
        {
        child=document.createElement("div");
        child.id=id;
        child.setAttribute("style","color:white;background-color:red;opacity:0.5;width:5px;height:300px; position:absolute;top:0px;left:"+mouseX+"px;font-size:9pt;");
        e.appendChild(child);
        var constraint=
        $("#"+id).resizable({
             maxHeight: 300,
             minHeight:300,
             minWidth: 1,
             maxWidth: 500,
            containment:"parent"
            });
        }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="margin-top:50px;margin-left:150px;">
<div id="x" onmousedown="javascript:myDrag(event,this)" style="position:relative;">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/72/Old_Man_with_Water_Studies.jpg/500px-Old_Man_with_Water_Studies.jpg" width="500" height="300"/>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can start the resize **as soon as  the user clicks on the image** ? I've tried `$("#"+id).trigger("resize");` with no success.

What is the right way to use [draggable.containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) here ?

Comment: So something like this? http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach? Needs refinement, but works:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #container { width:800px; height:600px; border:1px dotted #555; }
    #selector { z-index:100; position:absolute; width:100px; height:200px; border:1px dashed #555; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888; }
  </style>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).data('drag_mode', false);
        $(document).data('x', 0);
        $(document).data('y', 0);
        $(document).data('width', 0);
        $(document).data('height', 0);

        $('#container').on('mousedown', function(e) {
            $(document).data('drag_mode', true);
            $(document).data('x', e.pageX);
            $(document).data('y', e.pageY);
            $('#selector').css('left',e.pageX);
            $('#selector').css('top',e.pageY);
        });

        $('#container').on('mousemove', function(e) {
            if ($(document).data('drag_mode')) {
                $('#selector').css('width', (e.pageX - $(document).data('x')));
                $('#selector').css('height', (e.pageY - $(document).data('y')));
            }
        });

        $('#container').on('mouseup', function(e) {
            $(document).data('drag_mode', false);
        });

    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="selector">
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome Buddy. It's just a rough solution I put together real quick, you'll need to add some exception handling, behavior rules, and extra styling, but it should be more straight forward to read than the event object approach. Good luck.